# R: cofrequency tabel of categorical variables - heatmap / geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, categorical-data

Hello I would like to create heatmap presenting cofrequency of several variables 
Let's see some code:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1)
b <-c(1,1,1,0)
c<- c(1,1,0,0)
d <- c(1,0,0,0)

df <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
df
     a b c d
[1,] 1 1 1 1
[2,] 1 1 1 0
[3,] 1 1 0 0
[4,] 1 0 0 0
```

'1' represents occurence of a phenomenon
'0' the phenonenon did not appear

a and b cofrequency is 75%
a and c cofrequency is 50%
...

Finally, I would like to have 4x4 matrix with colnames on x and y axis and in tiles % of cofrequency
a vs a = 100%, a vs. b = 75% etc.

May I ask for a little help?

---

Solutions from comments generate:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
a <- c(1,1,1,1)
b <-c(1,1,1,0)
c<- c(1,1,0,0)
d <- c(1,0,0,0)
df <- cbind(a,b,c,d)
calc_freq <- function(x, y) {
  mean(df[, x] == df[, y] & df[, x] == 1 & df[, y] == 1)
}
mat <- outer(colnames(df), colnames(df), Vectorize(calc_freq))
mat
dimnames(mat) <- list(colnames(df), colnames(df))
mat %>% as_tibble() %>% gather %>% ggplot() + aes(key, value) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

I would rather to have % from `mat` as fill and x-axis and y-axis as `dinnames(mat)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a function directly doing this however, here is one base R approach using `outer`. We write a function which calculates ratio

```
calc_freq <- function(x, y) {
    mean(df[, x] == df[, y] & df[, x] == 1 & df[, y] == 1)
}
```

and apply it using `outer`

```
mat <- outer(colnames(df), colnames(df), Vectorize(calc_freq))
mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 1.00 0.75 0.50 0.25
#[2,] 0.75 0.75 0.50 0.25
#[3,] 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.25
#[4,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

If you want row and column names we can use `dimnames`

```
dimnames(mat) <- list(colnames(df), colnames(df))
```

This calculates the ratio of occurrence of 1 in two columns at the same position.

To get the plot we can do

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(mat) %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    gather(key, value, -rowname) %>%
    ggplot() + aes(rowname, key, fill = value) + 
    geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting function, and how to visualize this outcome of outer using for instance ggplot2 geom_tile?

Comment: @Mikołaj I think for that you need to reshape the data. something like `mat %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  gather %>%
  ggplot() + aes(key, value) + 
  geom_tile()`

Comment: hi, @RonakShah, if possible, can you explain the function? as I did not get it...

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini Hi..which part of the code did you not understand?

Comment: x and y in your function are the columns or the elements of each column, and the function is applied to each pair of columns?sorry, I am a bit lost

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini yes, exactly. So in `outer` we generate all possible combination of column names and in the function we subset the data with the help of those column names and calculate the ratio of it having equal 1 values.